# Which parts are these? Large yellow and orange pieces with Technic pin holes

Tags: part-identification

In an effort to identify sets in a second hand random LEGO collection we bought, we found some really obscure parts. Do you know which parts these are? Thanks!

[image: LEGO parts]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two parts on the right are [Cockpit 6 x 6 x 5 with Hinge (30619)](http://rebrickable.com/parts/30619). These have been used to make cockpits in LEGO Juniors and other very simple, low-part-count sets such as 4652:

[image: 4652]

The part on the left is Engine Block 4 x 6 x 2 with Wedge Cutouts and Technic Holes ([45407](https://rebrickable.com/parts/45407)). It is used to make up the front section of the tow truck shown above and has been used in similar ways in a few more sets in different colors.